# Returning Stream via File() causes future operations to throw "the process cannot access the file path because it is being used by another process"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filestream, memorystream, cryptostream

To decrease memory usage when returning a file to a client, whilst decrypting, we have gone with streams.
This was working fine until one quirk which is that when you upload the same file back to the server (e.g. when a client modifies it). It causes .net core to throw "the process cannot access the file path because it is being used by another process".

As this system is still in development, I'm unsure whether it's a quirk of running the application in debug mode rather than release. Although I built the code into release and still received the same error.

From what I'm aware of how return a stream works, it should dispose the streams automatically.

The first method that creates a stream contains the following:

```
return (await Decrypt(File.OpenRead(path), AesKey, AesIv), contentType);
```

The decrypt method then performs the following:

```
public static async Task<MemoryStream> Decrypt(FileStream data, string key, string iv)
{
    Aes aes = Aes.Create();

    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

    aes.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    aes.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv);

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

    return await PerformCryptography(data, decryptor);
}
```

This then calls the crypto method:

```
private static async Task<MemoryStream> PerformCryptography(FileStream data, ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    await data.CopyToAsync(cryptoStream);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return memoryStream;
}
```

This returns back up the chain to the controller that returns the following:

```
return File(file, contentType, fileName);
```

When I was developing this, it seemed wrapping any of these in using would cause an object disposed exception, however I may have done something wrong.

Does anyone know how to fix something like this?

Comment: "*From what I'm aware of how return a stream works, it should dispose the streams automatically.*" -- streams aren't disposed unless you call `.Dispose()` (or use a `using` block, which calls `.Dispose()` for you)

Comment: @canton7 I modified the code based on your response to this, however it now throws an "Cannot access closed stream" error

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                await data.CopyToAsync(cryptoStream);
            }memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return memoryStream;

Comment: Ah, you opened the `CryptoStream` over the `MemoryStream`, not the `FileStream`: I missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dispose the `FileStream` after you've finished copying its contents to the `CryptoStream`. An easy way to do this is with a `using` block inside `Decrypt`. Note that the `await` is inside the `using` block, so the `FileStream` won't be disposed until the `await` completes:

```
public static async Task<MemoryStream> Decrypt(FileStream data, string key, string iv)
{
    using (data)
    {
        Aes aes = Aes.Create();

        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        aes.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
        aes.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv);

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        return await PerformCryptography(data, decryptor);
    }
}
```

---

Another approach is to open the `CryptoStream` in Read mode over the `FileStream`. Instead of copying data into the `CryptoStream` (and the `CryptoStream` then writes that data to the `MemoryStream`), you read data out of the `CryptoStream` (and the `CryptoStream` pulls data from the `FileStream` as it needs):

```
private static async Task<MemoryStream> PerformCryptography(FileStream data, ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        await cryptoStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    }
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return memoryStream;
}
```

This lets you dispose the `CryptoStream` (which you should be disposing, because it's `IDisposable`) instead of calling `FlushFinalBlock()`, which is a bit neater. Disposing it also disposes the underlying `FileStream`.

---

If you're in a situation where you don't need to seek on the Stream which `Decrypt` returns (sadly this isn't the case if you're returning it from ASP.NET Core with `File(...)`), you can just return the `CryptoStream`. This means that the decryption happens as that stream is read, rather than upfront, which may not be what you want:

```
public static Stream Decrypt(FileStream data, string key, string iv)
{
    Aes aes = Aes.Create();

    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

    aes.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    aes.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv);

    return new CryptoStream(data, aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
}
```

---

I don't like how you're deriving your key and IV. ASCII only supports values 0 to 127, so your keyspace is only half the size it should be: you're effectively using AES-128 rather than AES-256. Likewise your IV is half the size it should be. Use a key derivation function like PBKDF2 to turn a (long) plain-text key into a proper 256-bit binary key.

Your IV is also suspect. Remember that everything you encrypt using a particular key needs to have a unique IV. That's very important. Do not re-use IVs!! It's common practice to randomly generate an IV when encrypting something, and to write that as the first few bytes of the ciphertext (it's fine if the IV is public, it just has to be unique). You can then extract that when decrypting.

Your padding is also slightly suspect: it means that any trailing 0's in the plaintext are removed by the encryption/decryption process. It's much better to use something like PKCS7.

Comment: @UncountedBrute Cool! Edited to add a few other notes

Comment: @UncountedBrute Added some additional notes about the security of your key and IV: please read!

Comment: @canton7 Nice answer, FYI, last line should be:
`return new CryptoStream(data, aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);`

Comment: @canton7 I've managed to get it to your suggestion of readmode. Moving to just returning cryptosteam seems to cause an error of "Stream does not support seek". Any ideas?
Regarding your comments about the key generations, any suggestions on docs to use to learn about the code?

Comment: Ah, maybe ASP.NET needs a seekable stream to return. Never mind that suggestion, then: you'll need the `MemoryStream`

Comment: @canton7 no worries, I added that as an edit to your solution.
Did you see my question about how to go about the PBKDF2 bit you mentioned, I'm struggling to find anything understandable online?

Comment: @UncountedBrute See [the examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-5.0).